# Rouché theorem in queuing theory

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, queueing-theory

I was looking for the uses of Rouché's theorem, and I came across queuing theory.
An article stated that it is a workhorse theorem in this field, but as much as I tried to find some examples on the ways it can be used I still could not.

Could someone show some examples or recommend me some articles / webpages where I can see how this theorem is used for calculating the probability generating function? (A not too complicated example would be nice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following article considers the application of Rouché's theorem in queueing theory.

[Adan, van Leeuwaarden and Winands. On the application of Rouché's theorem in queueing theory](http://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/books/590819.pdf)

For something I can really help you with if you have questions, see the proof of Lemma 4.5 in the following paper.

[Selen, Adan and van Leeuwaarden. Product-form solutions for a class of structured multi-dimenensional Markov processes](http://xxx.tau.ac.il/pdf/1310.8114v2.pdf)

After some digging I will be able to provide more examples, but maybe this will already be enough to give you some insight.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ritz, but I have already read the first paper. I would like to see an example, where the PGF is calculated with the help of Rouché's theorem. I see, I was not clear enough with my question, I'll edit it accordingly.

Comment: @user140832 In my (limited) knowledge, Rouché's theorem is applied to prove that a certain polynomial has a certain number of roots in a bounded region $K$ with a continuous boundary $\delta K$. So, the theorem is not used to actually compute these roots (and thus does not actually compute the PGF), it only shows that there are a certain number of roots in a bounded region. Usually this region is the unit disc.  As an example, see Lemma 4.5 in the second paper I referenced. One proves that a polynomial has a certain number of roots in the unit disc, but does not compute these roots.